# Nuget package sources not being saved

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget

My NuGet package manager cannot save new or find existing package sources.

The location where the package sources are saved %appdata%\NuGet\nuget.config is not getting updated since the problem started. Deleting it does not re-create it when I try adding a new package source through the Visual Studio -> Package Manager Sources dialog.

"Package Manager sources" dialog always shows empty on trying to save something and re-opening the dialog.

This problem started on my laptop after changing my corporate password from my office desktop computer (which does not have this issue).

Re-installing "Nuget Package Manager" did not help. Re-installing Visual Studio did not help.

Answer (score 7):

My problem is fixed :)

The step of deleting %appdata%\NuGet\nuget.config may have helped along with other steps.

Restarting Visual Studio re-generated this file with nuget.org package source added. I am almost sure I had tried this before but it had not worked before.
The only other major difference was that I was not connected to corporate VPN network when restarting Visual Studio.

After searching everywhere, doesn't look like anyone has faced (or at-least asked) this issue. Hope this posting helps someone in the future.

Comment: You probably did try it before and had it not work. It didn't work for me when I opened Visual Studio without opening a solution. When I deleted the file and then opened a solution, it recreated the nuget.config file and worked.

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted the package source that didn't want to update, and readded it.